# Javascript, regular expression and {n,m}

Tags: javascript, regex

I just noticed a very strange behaviour. Why does a simple space break all the tests?

```
rePattern = /^([a-z]+[-_]?){2,}[a-z]$/; 
var test = new Array("jhgfg_hfh-g", "jhg-fg_hfhg", "jhg_fg_hfhg", "jhg_fg_hfhg", "jhg_fghfhg");
for (var i = 0; i < test.length ; i++) {
   x = test[i];
   alert(i + ' : ' + x + ' : ' + rePattern.test( x ));
}
```

if i change the above to

```
// notice {2,} => {2, } with an extra space before }
rePattern = /^([a-z]+[-_]?){2, }[a-z]$/;
```

then everything become `false`...

thank u

Comment: Because of the extra space, obviously. The syntax of regular expressions is strict, you can't add random whitespace and expect it'll be ignored. `{2, }` will match literal `{2, }`.

Comment: @duri your comment is the answer, why don't you post it as answer?

Comment: ok, sorry, i was quite sure that it was ok.. just test it in python and you are also right there...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, just to have an accepted answer here: it's because of the extra space. The syntax of regular expressions is strict, you can't add random whitespace and expect it'll be ignored. `{2, }` will match literal `{2, }`:

```
/^x{2, }$/.test('x{2, }') === true
```

Comment: +1 I think most people don't know that the `{}` brackets are matched literally as soon as they are not part of the quantifier.

Answer (score 0):

Your regexp does'nt work when you add a space at the begin or end of tested value because you use the regexp delemiters ^ and $

- ^ says that the pattern catch to the start of the string
- $ says that the pattern catch to the end of the string

If you combine the two delimiters, the regexp will react to all the caracters including the spaces.

So use the following regexp to catch any string which following the pattern :

```
/([a-z]+[-_]?){2,}[a-z]/
```

Comment: actually i do not get the thing here... i wanted to be sure to have an initial and ending alpha, if i forget ^and $ i would match only part that can accept this regexp, no ?

and having /([a-z]+[-_]?){2, }[a-z]/ will not accept any of these also. (you write "If you combine the two delimiters, the regexp will react to all the caracters including the spaces.") even without, the {2,<extraspace>} will not work... I think that the only answer is the one of Duri, no ?

Comment: Ok ! You're right my previous answer isn't good. If i understood your problem you need to check if your string have alpha characters at start and end.

The following regexp should solved your problem :

    /^([a-z])+(.)+([a-z])+$/

Comment: problem solved ^^ and my expression was ok for my need, only allowing [a-] or -_ but not consecutive for these two. My trouble was actually the extraspace as explained by Duri. Thank u.

Comment: Can you give me some available and forbidden string examples ?

Comment: Ptiswitz, thank u for your help, but it is now ok (as told earlier). I get the point, and i'm ok in writing my regexps. My initial question was actually and only on the "space" behaviour inside {n,m} as i used to add some extra spaces almost anywhere before my {}()[]. Best.